# Subclassing MKAnnotationView with use of auto layout

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, mkannotationview, autolayout

I like the new auto layout functionality in iOS 6 but I've run into a bit of trouble when using it in combination with my MKAnnotationView subclass.

I've disabled the autoresizing mask translation in the initialization method.

```
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

But the app throws an NSInternalInconsistencyException when I load the MKMapView that uses an annotation of my subclass.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[ENMapAnnotationView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UIView.m:5776
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. ENMapAnnotationView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

I don't override -layoutSubviews so to me this looks like Apple's implementation of MKAnnotationView isn't ready for auto layout. **Is there some smart way to get around the lack of auto layout support in MKAnnotationView so I can use auto layout in my subclass?**

Comment: In the end I rewrote the whole thing without using autolayout. So I'm afraid I don't have a solution.

Comment: Maybe also a solution for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19623817/701900

Answer (score 6):

AutoLayout for annotation views worked fine until iOS SDK 8. With iOS SDK 8 I see really strange behaviour of views with dynamic constraints, they are moving all over the map or sometimes even align top left.

Solution was `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES` and

```
[annotationView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
```

and use width and height calculated from the subviews. Then at least you can use constraints for the subviews.

Comment: I'm amazed! This actually worked. I was using Masonry, so that sets the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO automatically, hence I had to manually set it to YES at the end of updateConstraints.

Answer (score 4):

Don't disable the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of your ENMapAnnotationView (or you will miss the Pin).
And make sure the enable the view which you want to add to the ENMapAnnotationView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints!!!

```
photoViewAddToAnnotationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

That's it! We don't need to turn off Auto layout (Turn off the Auto layout may solve the problem as well'

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have to implement the - (void)layoutSubviews method in your ENMapAnnotaitonView class.

Comment: I've tried that but this did not work. When overriding the -layoutSubviews method I need to call its super method for auto layout to work. But since it seems like MKAnnotationView implements its own -layoutSubviews method without calling its super the call will never reach the -layoutSubviews method of UIView which I think causes the exception.